# laravel accessors not working with select() statement

Tags: laravel

Laravel accessors not working when there is select statement in query.

```
App\Models\Doctor::select('name')->first()->doctor_name
```

I also have added accessors name in appends

```
protected $appends = ['doctor_name'];
```

and tried by using full function name

```
App\Models\Doctor::first()->getDoctorNameAttribute()
```

This only works when I don't use select() in query

[image]

what is the solution ?

Comment: Because, if you select only `name` field - where eloquent can get `title` field?\

Comment: you are right! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must select the field where you established the accessor, **doctor_name** in this case

```
App\Models\Doctor::select(['name', 'doctor_name'])->first()->doctor_name
```

It works when you don't use select() because it select all fields.